# Unable to select highest value from a column

Tags: php, mysql

I have suffered with this for to long. It is turning me nuts...

I just want to take the max value of a column, add 1 to id  and then insert a new entry.

The table has a column 'id' and lets say 'name' and 'age'

The problem is that the $new_id variable is not selecting the highest value from the id column.   I know I am doing something wrong... but what??
Please help, I know this must be a pretty basic issue, but I have been looking at this for hours...

```
$relations_table="xxx_sobipro_relations";

$sql="SELECT * FROM '$relations_table' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$new_id = $row[id] + 1;

//more code

$query="INSERT INTO $relations_table (id, pid, oType, position, validSince)
VALUES ($new_id, 2, 'testtest' , $position , NOW() )";
```

Comment: What database are you using?  Does it not support some sort of `auto-increment` functionality?

Comment: This is a hack into the sobipro component.  So , no I cant use auto increment. Thanks

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `_array` and quote array keys (`$row['id']`. Also **don't use the `mysql_` extension anymore for new code, it is _deprecated_.**

Comment: @Wrikken Why not `_array`? It includes both numeric and named keys.

Comment: @Barmar: ah, you're correct, it's been such a long time I worked with `mysql_*` stuff I confused `mysql_fetch_row` & `mysql_fetch_array`, apologies.

Answer (score 4):

Use this instead:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id)+1,0) FROM `$object_table`
```

Comment: Just to supplement a little: the COALESCE is there to handle the case that there aren't any rows yet in the table or it has been cleared (for example).

Comment: Combine it with dropping the quotes as in Lars' answer, and we have a winner ;)

Comment: @Wrikken Indeed, fixed. OP: Backticks are appropriate here, not single quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the COALESCE function but I still have the same issue.  Am I fetching the result correctly?is there a sytax problem.  I think I will have to install an IDE to debug.  as it has me...

Comment: Make sure you also use $ row ['id'] when fetching it

Comment: Do I have a problem with my quotes/backticks?  Guys i am going crazy,  .!!

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM `$object_table`
```

table names and field names not in '' but `` (backticks)

And you should ask the database for errors...

and you should NOT use the mysql extension anymore, but switch to mysqli or PDO...

Answer (score 1):

You should look into AUTO_INCREMENT - turning that on for your id column will cause it to increase by one automatically every time you insert a row. That way, you won't have to specify id when you do the insertion, because MySQL keeps track of it for you.

Comment: I understand but the table is part of a component (sobipro).  The column is part of a two column primary key. So adding autoincrement wouldnt work i think.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this on your insert:

```
$query="INSERT INTO $relations_table (id, pid, oType, position, validSince) 
    VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id)+1 FROM $object_table), 2, 'testtest' , $position , NOW() )";
```

Auto_increment is a better option, but this will work when you can't auto_increment.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's `$row['id']` not `$row[id]`.

Second, `mysql_*` is deprecated, do not use it. Instead use `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Third, you can use `MAX` to get maximum value from column. `SELECT MAX(id) FROM '$object_table' LIMIT 1`.

And most important, set `id` field to `autoincrement` and don't set it (MySQL will do it).

Answer (score 0):

So, the query you're looking for is:

```
SELECT MAX(id) FROM table
```

But many databases provide an "auto-increment" functionality where you can specify a column (in this case `id`) to be the primary key and have its value auto-increment, so you don't have to do any of this.